# How to avoid double dash seem as a continuous line?

Tags: fonts, spacing, listings

I'm using `listings` to show some source code (bash scripts) in my document but there is a problem, when using mono spaced fonts, the space between dashes is very small and in the printed document two or more contiguous dashes seems as a continuous line.

The courier font hasn't this problem, but I would like to use Bera Mono or DejaVu Sans Mono.

Is there a way to avoid this situation?

**EDIT:** This is the code that reproduces the problem, I am using `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{code}
{
    \fontsize{10pt}{1pt}
    \usefont{T1}{fvm}{m}{n}
    \lstset
    {
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false
    }
} { }

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
    diff --version | head -n1
    find --version | head -n1
    gawk --version | head -n1
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

I like Herbert's solution but I added the code only to clarify how this problem happen.

Comment: Do you change the font, or do you use `listings`, `verbatim` or even `alltt`? As far as I know, none of the latter have this issue.

Comment: Which TeX format are you using -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX? If you use the `fontspec` package, have you enabled the option `Ligatures=TeX` option for monospaced fonts? Please advise.

Comment: I'm using `pdflatex`.  The problem is when I use listings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see it:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}%% when running xelatex or lualatex
\usepackage{listings}
%\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\usepackage{dejavu}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
---
--
-
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I suppose that my problem is in the form I specify the font.